# How to add a texture on top of another one

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm a beginner, so please bear with me. I think there is a simple solution to my question but I can't find it.

I want to use two different textures on my model: a gold texture (that comes with normal, metal, roughness layers etc.) AND a texture I painted on photoshop and applied on a UV map.

UV map:
[image]

SO I want the whole character to have the gold texture, except his eyes and a part of his face. For those, I want the photoshop texture. So on the UV map I colored via photoshop, I colored only the eyes and the part of the face I want with this texture, I left the rest blank.

My goal is to put the photoshop texture on top of the gold layer.

I tried 2 ways:
-method 1: I created 2 materials: one for each texture, and set up my nodes. However, what appears on screen is one of the two textures, depending on which material is on top of the other: the empty parts of the photoshop texture don't show the golden texture that should be underneath, it only shows black.

-method 2: I created only 1 material, and used an rgb mix node to connect each texture to a color slot of the rgb ix node. Then I connected that mix to the principled BSDF. This time the photoshop texture is combined with the gold texture, everything is at the right place BUT the "properties" of the golden texture (metallic, roughness...) have been applied to the photoshop layer as well, which I want to avoid. So how can I split the golden texture properties from the photoshop texture?
[image]

If you need more pictures or any file to answer the questions, don't hesitate to tell me! It would be awesome to get some help!

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of what happens if I use a mix shader and plug the alpha channel of my texture image to the factor of the mix shader:
[image]

Comment: you need to use a Mix Shader, plug your 2 materials into the 2 inputs, and use the alpha channel of your image as a mask in the factor input of the Mix Shader

Comment: Hi @moonboots I followed your instructions but I don't know how to "use the alpha channel of your image as a mask". Do you have a link with explanations about the masking part? I plugged both textures to the mix shader but I don't know how to go further.

Comment: it looks like your image is a PNG with a transparent background (i.e. alpha channel) so you need to use the Alpha output socket of the Image Texture, plug it into the Factor input of the Mix Shader

Comment: @moonboots thank you, I did that but then my PNG disapears and I only see the gold texture on the model (I'm joining a screenshot to my post so you can see)

Comment: maybe switch the two materials in the Mix Shader? Or pack your image (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots when I switch both materials the png takes over the gold one: I only see the png. So I'll share my file

Comment: @moonboots wetransfer was more rapid so here is the link: https://we.tl/t-krP6JxsUCc   I hope I properly packed it, otherwise tell me and I'll do it again

Comment: it seems like you've used a psd, could you please convert it to png, use it within your material instead of the psd, pack and share again?

Comment: Also, your mesh is super high-poly, why don't you keep it low-poly and give it a Subdivision Surface in order to smooth it?

Comment: @moonboots sorry for the psd file I thought it didn't matter, I'm preparing another link now. I am aware my file is super high poly but it was made by someone else: I just want to apply textures over it, that's why I don't modify the original model

Comment: @moonboots here is the new file: https://we.tl/t-baAmeprx8l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plug a *Diffuse* between your *Image Texture* and your *Mix Shader* (otherwise the image won't display in Cycles and will display as an *Emission* in Eevee), erase the black color on your PNG so that you only have transparency (do it in your image editor software but you can also do it in Blender), and in the 3D View switch to *Render* mode to see the real result:

[image]

Once you've deleted the black parts:

[image]

Also maybe load an HDRI image for your world so that the gold material has something to reflect, but here we can see the golden part nevertheless.

Comment: it works!!! Thank you so so much for your help!!